# Copy with percentage completion

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, xcopy

I'm currently trying to create a batch file, which actually copy a folder from a server to a clients machine. And I'm playing around with batch file, using xcopy, and it gives me the percentage of completion. I'm not a programmer, i just modified a tiny mount of lines from a code which i got from: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120229012108AA8EwOA (all credit goes to "Jake").

However, the batch file will actually copied the whole files, including the parent folders, did i miss something here?

Here is the code:

```
@echo off&color a
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /
mkdir ZZZDestination
set startdir="C:\ZZZSource\Depth1\Depth2\the files"
set enddir="C:\ZZZDestination\"

echo.
echo Press any key to continue
PAUSE>nul

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in ('dir /s %startdir%^|findstr bytes') do if /i not "%%e"=="free" set qtyfiles=%%a
set filecount=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /a-d-h-s /s /b %startdir%') do (
xcopy /z /q /s /e /y "%%a" "%enddir%\%%~pa\*.*" >nul
set /a filecount=!filecount!+1
set /a percentage=!filecount!*100 / !qtyfiles!
cls
echo.
echo Copying files, PLEASE DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW
echo ======================================================
echo Please wait for copying:       !percentage!%% Completed
echo ======================================================
)
echo.
echo DONE, please press any key to exit..
PAUSE>nul
```

I have tried to modified the

```
xcopy /z /q /s /e /y "%%a" "%enddir%\%%~pa\*.*" >nul
```

into

```
xcopy /z /q /s /e /y "%%a" "%enddir%" >nul
```

It works, and does not copy the parent folders (e.g. ZZZSource\Depth1\Depth2).
However, the files inside the sub-folders under "C:\ZZZSource\Depth1\Depth2\the files" will be copied out from the folder.

For example, under folder "C:\ZZZSource\Depth1\Depth2\the files", there are folders A B C, and inside those, there are each 4-5 files. Those 4-5 files, will all be copied out into "C:\ZZZDestination\" instead of under "C:\ZZZDestination\A\" for example.

Anyone have any idea?

Thank you in advance.